# The distance of a point to a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>1$, and $x$ a point outside $F$. We know that there exists a point $y\in F$ such that the distance between $x$ and $F$ is attained at $y$, i.e., d$(x,F)=d(x,y)=a>0$. Suppose $b>a$. How to prove that there is a point $z$ such that $x$ belongs to the segment $[z,y]$ and such that d$(z,y)=b?$ This is clear intuitively, and
notice that if $b<a$, then $z\in [x,y]$ and the result is a consequence of intermediate value theorem.

Comment: It is intuitively clear. If you draw a picture, you can see how to write $z$ explicitly in terms of $a,b,x,y$.

Comment: Clearly the line through $x,y$ includes points at distance $b$ from $y$, for any $b\ge 0$. Are you asking for a formal proof of this?

Comment: Yes. A formal proof.

Comment: You mean set $z=y+b(x-y)/a$? Is there a way to extend this result to any metric space?

Comment: It's not true in a general metric space.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is actually false.

Take $F = \{p: |p| \ge 1\}$, the complement of the open ball of radius $1$ around the origin. $F$ is clearly closed. Take $x$ to be the origin: there is no point farther from $F$ than $x$ is.

I think if you assume also that $F$ is bounded, the statement is true. Similarly if $F$ is convex.